# Partitioning on two columns with discrete values

Tags: postgresql, performance, partitioning

I have a table with 10 billion rows in Postgres.

The columns are:

`user_id | entity_1 | f1 | ... | f5 | start_time | end_time`

As you can see, this table holds the data of all of the users.

None of the users can reach the data of other users.

Moreover, the field `entity_1` will always be filtered on a specific value.

Because of the information above, I think it is a good idea to separate somehow the table by `user_id` and `entity_1`. To improve performance mainly.

I thought about partitioning.

How to partition by 2 columns with discrete values, simultaneously? Moreover, how will I do this automatically? As the creation of new users and new `entity_1` happens all the time.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? Is there a query that is taking too long? What is the full definition of the table?

Comment: Can a user_id appear for more than one entity? If not, then you probably want to partition by `entity_1` then sub-partition by `user_id`. But there is nothing that will automatically create the partitions. You need to do that manually.

Comment: @bbaird
I want to prepare for the future. I know that partitioning may be a good practice to improve ingestion and read time, so I much prefer to implement best practices from start.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Each `user_id` has many `entity_1`s. No `entity_1` can exist for more than 1 user.
Why not partition by `user_id` and then by `entity_1`? Moreover, isn't it the same as just creating a dedicated table for each `user_id`-`entity_1` permutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partition is a normal table in PostgreSQL, so it can be a partitioned table as well. This way, you could "subpartition" your table, for example by `entity_1` first, and each partition is partitioned by `user_id`.

But if your goal is improved performance, it is doubtful whether you will achieve it by partitioning. Partitioning only helps with performance for very specific queries. Most queries actually become *slower* with partitioning. So test your queries carefully before you partition like this. My guess is that a proper index or two is what you need for good performance.

Comment: Don't you think there will be benefits in query performance because I will always filter on `user_id` and `entity_1`?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have indexes for those columns, the queries will probably become *slower* by partitioning. But then, if you *don't* have indexes on these columns, the queries will become faster, and you can save yourself an index. So it is hard to tell without knowing your important queries. Only don't fall into the trap of believing that partitioning will automatically be good for performance.

Comment: Got you. Thank you for your insight. I'll test things out and see what performs better based on your suggestions.